# Extracting residuals from ur.za

Tags: r

I want to check residuals for autocorrelation and heteroskedasticity in Zivot and Andrews unit root test. Any idea how I can extract the residuals?

I tried

```
za.institutions <- ur.za(institutions.ts,model = "both", lag = 3)
resid.institut= resid(za.institutions)
```

but did only get an error:

> $ operator not defined for this S4 class

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `ur.za` returns S4-class object

```
za.institutions@res
```

sholud work.